# Url Connection timed out

Tags: java

I am trying to access the url using below mentioned code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null,CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
    // http://www.google.com/
    // http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG&f=g
    **URL oracle = new URL("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=XOM+EK+JNJ+MSFT&f=snd1t1l1ohgvwdyr");
    URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            yc.getInputStream()));**
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)

        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
}
```

This code is working fine in my home but same code is not working in office and i am getting error like this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at com.yahoo.Connection.main(Connection.java:21)
```

I am suspecting there can be firewall or proxy issue but i am not sure.

Does anyone know of way to work around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you behing some corporate proxy by any chance?

Comment: This is a network topology problem. You can't connect to that site from where you are. Some intervening firewall, probably your own, is preventing it. Talk to your netadmin.

Comment: Can you access the same URL through a web browser? If yes, what are the proxy settings of the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably behind some corporate proxy.

If yes try this code to enable programmatically a proxy:

```
private boolean proxyEnabled = true;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL oracle = new URL("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=XOM+EK+JNJ+MSFT&f=snd1t1l1ohgvwdyr");
    URLConnection yc;
    if(proxyEnabled) {
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("my.proxy.example.com", 3128));
        yc = oracle.openConnection(proxy);
    } else {
        yc = oracle.openConnection();
    }
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)

        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try setting these properties for your program. With them java should be able to use your proxy. That is, as long as you have the information on hand.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "your proxyhost");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "your proxyport");
```

Comment: thx for reply and it worked in windows machine and i tried to execute in Linux box i was getting "407 error(authentication problem)" even though i have passed the proxy and credentials details  in code itself. 
"System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", "user");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", "password");" but no use and i tried do java -Dhttp.proxyHost="111.88.15.108" -Dhttp.proxyPort="8002" -Dhttp.proxyUser="user" -Dhttp.proxyPassword="password"  -jar yahoo_test3.jar and same error